# Upload Images in Loop React

Tags: reactjs, loops, for-loop, file-upload

I would like to send post request after every 10 count (ie. i = 10) (Slice 10 array of object from ImageObject and send it to backend). But i cant seem to update the state.

eg. if my ImageObject length === 500 , after every 10 loop , slice 10 array from ImageObject and send it to backend and so on untill ImageObject === 0

```
 import { useState } from "react";
 import axios from "axios";
 import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

 import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
 import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";

 type ImageType = {
 name: string;
  };

   export default function App() {
   const [mediaPath, setMediaPath] = useState<ImageType[]>([]);
   const [file, setFile] = useState<File[]>([]);

  const handleImagePaths = async (paths: ImageType[]) => {
  try {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  await axios.post(
    `/api/folders/uploads`,
    {
      media: paths
    },
    options
  );
  } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  }
  };
  const handleUpload = async () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
  const imgFile = file[i];

  // aws-sdk upload
  const id = uuidv4();
  const path = `folder/${imgFile.name}`;

  let ImageObject: ImageType[] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < file.length; j++) {
    ImageObject.push({
      name: file[j].name
    });
  }
  setMediaPath(ImageObject);

  if (i % 10 === 0) {
    const paths = ImageObject.slice(0, 10);
    handleImagePaths(paths);
  }
  const target = {
    Bucket: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: path,
    Body: imgFile,
    ContentType: "image/jpeg"
  };
  const creds = {
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || "",
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || ""
  };
  try {
    const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
      client: new S3Client({
        region: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION || "",
        credentials: creds
      }),
      leavePartsOnError: true,
      partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1000,
      params: target
    });

    parallelUploads3.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress: any) => {});

    await parallelUploads3.done();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
};
return (
<div className="App">
  <h1>Send Post API After every 10 loop</h1>
</div>
);
}
```

Help !!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";

type ImageType = {
name: string;
} ;

export default function App() {
const [mediaPath, setMediaPath] = useState<ImageType[]>([]);
const [file, setFile] = useState<File[]>([]);

const handleImagePath = async (index: number, path: any, len: number) => {
if (index % 10 === 0 && index > 1) {
  const paths = path.splice(0, 10);
  try {
    await axios.post(`/api/folders`, {
      media: paths,
    });
  } catch (error) {
   console.error(error)
  }
} else if (index === len - 1) {
  const paths = path;
  try {
    await axios.post(`/api/folders`, {
      media: paths,
    });
  } catch (error) {
   console.error(error)
  }
}
};
const handleUpload = async () => {
for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
const imgFile = file[i];



const path = `folder/${imgFile.name}`;

 mediaPath.push({
    name: file[i].name,
  });
  handleImagePath(i, mediaPath, file.length);

const target = {
Bucket: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_AWS_BUCKET,
Key: path,
Body: imgFile,
ContentType: "image/jpeg"
};
const creds = {
accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || "",
secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || ""
};
try {
const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
  client: new S3Client({
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION || "",
    credentials: creds
  }),
  leavePartsOnError: true,
  partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1000,
  params: target
});

parallelUploads3.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress: any) => {});

await parallelUploads3.done();
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
}
};
return (
<div className="App">
<h1>Send Post API After every 10 loop</h1>
</div>
);
}
```